# SNOWFLAKE: Determine the ROW NUMBER to return based on 0 value present

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The following query picks up the first order for every supplier.  but the query needs to be refined in a way that it should ignore the
PO_NUMBER = 0 per supplier UNLESS that is the only supplier history on record.  Every SUPPLIER will have at least one PO_NUMBER = 0.

So I will use either

(1) `ROWNUM = 1`  if there is only one history for the supplier regardless of whether the PO_NUMBER is 0 or not,  OR when there is no PO_NUMBER = NULL for the supplier,

or

(2) use  `ROWNUM = 2`  if there are more histories for the supplier and he has a record with PO_NUMBER = 0.

> ```
> SELECT   SUPPLIER_CODE, 
>          SUPPLIER_NAME,
>          DELIVERY_LOCATION,
>          RECEIVED_BY,
>          ORDER_DATE,
>          PO_NUMBER,
>          DELIVERY_DATE
>          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SUPPLIER_CODE
>                             ORDER BY SUPPLIER_CODE, DELIVERY_DATE, PO_NUMBER) AS ROWNUM
> FROM  DELIVERY_HISTORY  
> WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
> ```

Inputs are appreciated.

Comment: Could you just do something like `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SUPPLIER_CODE ORDER BY DELIVERY_DATE, CASE WHEN PO_NUMBER = 0 THEN 9999999999999 ELSE PO_NUMBER)` It's a little hokey, but sticking `0` PO Numbers at the end of your sort should do the trick.

Comment: Will there be multiple PO_NUMBER values on the same DELIVERY_DATE?  Could you just sort DESC on PO_NUMBER?

Comment: Also, if you are partitioning by SUPPLIER_CODE, no need to include SUPPLIER_CODE in your ORDER BY.

Comment: Lastly, I think the code above may give you an error, anyway.  You need to either move the select into a sub-query before filtering on ROWNUM=1, or my favorite, use QUALIFY.  Like, `QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER()`....` = `1` after the FROM DELIVERY_HISTORY.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two steps:

- Get the first order with `0`, and the first order that's not `0`.
- Then you will have 2 rows for each customer (or 1, if only `0`s), select the one that has the highest order_id.

```sql
with data as (
    select $1 customer, $2 the_date, $3 prop2, $4 order_id 
    from values(1,'2022-01-01',3,0), (1,'2022-01-03',3,5), (1,'2022-01-03',3,6)
        , (2,'2022-01-04',7,0), (2,'2022-01-05',4,0), (2,'2022-01-06',8,0)
        , (3,'2022-01-07',7,0), (3,'2022-01-08',4,0), (3,'2022-01-09',8,0), (3, '2022-01-10', 20, 8), (3, '2022-01-11', 11, 8), (3, '2022-01-12', 20, 18)
)

select *
from (
    select *
    from data
    qualify row_number() over(partition by customer, order_id=0 order by the_date) = 1
)
qualify row_number() over(partition by customer order by order_id desc) = 1
```

[image]